# htaccess- only one page redirects from html to php

Tags: html, .htaccess

This is normal question, but i am very weak regarding .htaccess

I have one website in html.All Pages are in .html. Now only enquiry page is enquiry.php

So I want enquiry page from enquiry.php to enquiry.html in URL.

It should not affect other html files

Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Provided you've already turned "RewriteEngine On" your rule might looks something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^enquiry.html$ /enquiry.php [QSA,L]
```

However depending upon your web host, that may not work out of the gate. For example, you might need to add a slash before the .html so it would read:

```
RewriteRule ^enquiry\.html$ /enquiry.php [QSA,L]
```

I've also seen where you may need to add "Options FollowSymLinks" to the top of the .htaccess file.